AWS IAM resource policy and Lambda Role not working
I have a question regarding AWS Lambdas and setting the Access(resource_ policy on AWS Opensearch (using Elasticsearch 6.8 under the hood)
What I want to do is to set up the following access policy on AWS Opensearch. It seems a bit weird, but this is necessary to do it this way for some reasons (I wont go into detail on those yet)
(1) I want ALL roles (AWS: ) to be able to everything (es:) EXCEPT for them not to be able to delete anything from my Opensearch instance. In other words I want to prevent them from doing an ESHTTPDelete operation.
(2) However, I DO want STILL the Lambda (that has the role arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/testelk-purge-elk-role to be still able to do the ESHTTPDelete.
Therefore, my actual access policy that I have is as follows: (Obviously I have changed the names). This should work, although it is a bit convoluted. HOWEVER, it does not work due to some way that Lambdas are using their execution role that I am not yet understanding. Any ideas or help on this area would be appreciated.
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-west-2:123456789:domain/domain-elktest/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "NotPrincipal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/testelk-purge-elk-role"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "es:ESHttpDelete",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-west-2:123456789:domain/domain-elktest/*"
    }
  ]
}

The above, I think, should work. However, the error I get when I run the lambda is as follows:

Index logstash-2024.03.28 delete error Authorization Exception ::
{"path":"/logstash-2024.03.28","query":{},"statusCode":403,"response":"{"Message":"User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/testelk-purge-elk-role/testelk-purge-elk
is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpDelete with an explicit deny in
a resource-based policy"}"}


Try this
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-west-2:123456789:domain/domain-elktest/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:ESHttpDelete",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:eu-west-2:123456789:domain/domain-elktest/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/testelk-purge-elk-role",
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


This policy worked perfectly. Thanks very much. (I also have an alternative that I will post, but I prefer your answer. Am only sharing my alternative for more info in case it may be useful later on)

The alternative is to use the format as follows. (this also worked, although I prefer your answer).It is the same as above, except the Condition is as follows:
"Condition": {
"ArnNotEquals": {
"lambda:SourceFunctionArn": [
"arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:123456789:function:testelk-purge-elk"
]
}
}
